# HTTP Handler Inefficient for an array of images

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, httphandler

I have an HTTP Handler that returns images stored as `VARBINARY(MAX)` from a database. The `ImageURL` property in a `Repeater` is set as:

```
ImageUrl='<%# "~/ImageHandler.ashx?PictureId=" + Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'
```

It works. However, the real problem with this code is that the `Page_Load` method of the page returns a list of "PictureId"'s from the database, then the `ImageHandler.ashx' makes *separate, individual calls* to the database for each image. This is just too many round trips to the DB.

I'm looking for a way to get all of the images in one shot and display them in a `Repeater`. Converting the images to Base64 seemed like a viable option until I realized that there is no caching available. How else could I do this? I'm fine with HTTP Handlers doing the work, but it's got to be in one shot. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on how you are binding your repeater control. Can you please provide a code example of your pade_load event? I want to see your data fetching and data binding code.

Comment: Well, the `ImageUrl` property above is in the `Repeater`. The `Page_Load` event calls the database and just get a list of `PictureId`'s. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the approach You're using is going to give You the same result on every individual call as you're using PictureId to get every unique image in the database.

Approach-1.

In order to achieve the concern You have, what you can do is hit the database at first and get all the images from database and keep in generic list. Now from that generic list parse the images and supply to repeater.

Approach-2. I haven't tried following code but I hope it may give You an idea how You could get what You want.

For dispalying image in repeater control:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Image FROM Images">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
   <itemtemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
   </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in aspx.cs

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   HiddenField hf =  e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
   if (hf != null)
   {
       string val = hf.Value;
       Image img = e.Item.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
       img.ImageUrl =  string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",val);
   }
}
```

Note: You can't use HTTP Handler to get all the images in one hit based on a PictureId.

**Edited->**

Addition to Your caching concern the truth is, that without having the image (for browser an HTTP Resource) physically present on Your server caching can't be served by web browser. What You can do is 
1) use client side script to call the images from server by building an API
2) or go with Base64 conversion as there's no other option although it will increase bandwidth utilization

You've basically combined two different questions in one. Because overcoming HTTP Handler for multiple requests is one situation and providing cache is another.

For web browser caching feature You should have http resource (image file) present on Your web server as I said but if You are concerned with performance then alternate to caching, you could compress Your image using some compression mechanism, it will save some bandwidth and load time of Your page. Here's a good [read](https://trikks.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/compress-a-file-using-gzip-and-convert-it-to-base64-and-back-using-c/). Comment if this is still not helping or mark this as answer.

Comment: Good answer, but as I noted I don't want to use Base64 as this makes HTTP caching impossible. It also bloats the HTML size heavily. However, I'm interested in your first approach. So I would parse the DB, populate a generic list compose of `byte[]` arrays then how would I actually display the images?